# Can't connect to postgres using a URI, but can connect with psql -U

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to set up a simple web server on digital ocean and I'm having trouble connecting to the database with sqlalchemy using a URI.

Running

```
root@maudlin:/server/http/maudlin# psql postgresql://maudlin:<password>@localhost/maudlin
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

fails but running

```
root@maudlin:/server/http/maudlin# psql -U maudlin
Password for user maudlin: <password>
psql (12.7 (Ubuntu 12.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

maudlin=>
```

passes.

As far as I can tell my pg_hba.conf file allows local ip connections:

```
# This file is read on server startup and when the server receives a
# SIGHUP signal.  If you edit the file on a running system, you have to
# SIGHUP the server for the changes to take effect, run "pg_ctl reload",
# or execute "SELECT pg_reload_conf()".
#
# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------
#
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.
host    maudlin         maudlin         <personal ip 1>/32         md5
host    maudlin         maudlin         <personal ip 2>/32        md5


# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Doesn't the line

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

mean accept ipv4 connections on local host with password using md5?

I imagine I could add the machine's ip to the top list of external ips and route my connections through that but that seams like a Bad Idea™

Does anyone have any debug tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had modified my `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf`:

Changing

```
listen_addresses = '<machine ip>'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

to

```
listen_addresses = '<machine ip>, localhost'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

and restarting solved the problem.